# Which fonts were used in this presentation?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[Lessons learned defying Joel Spolsky with Django](https://speakerdeck.com/nickbruun/lessons-learned-defying-joel-spolsky-with-django) by Nick Bruun

[image]

[image]

I love the fonts - would really appreciate help in identifying the fonts.

Comment: I didn't really check that out properly, but that thing does have 71 pages. Even if it would have just one font in all 71 pages, I wouldn't know that until I go through every single page. I know for sure that I'm not going to check every one of them. You should tell us what pages you mean and specify what text as well.

Comment: Maybe add a schreenshot as well?

Answer (score 11):

The font is called [Bariol](http://www.bariol.com/).

[image: Bariol screenshot from its website]

And, so you know how I figured it out (even though I've never heard of the font before), I downloaded the presentation PDF and then opened it in Illustrator. Illustrator was happy to tell me which fonts were missing from my system:

[image: Screenshot of Illustrator error]

Comment: +1 for sharing the method: PDF preflight info is also how I figure out/simulate brand colors etc. when someone can't or won't provide a branding document.

Answer (score 3):

definitely the Bariol, -Thin , -Light, -Regular and -Bold

[image: document properties]